# Problem with numbering theorem by section

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am having a problem with the numbering of the theorems (by section) in a paper. My problem is that I want to number my theorems and propositions such that they appear as something like:

Theorem 3.1, Proposition 3.1 etc.

However, using the current list of commands I have, I am getting the following:

Theorem 31, Proposition 31 etc.

It seems like at least for the theorem command that I have put in, it is the usual command to call when trying to number theorems by section, so I am a little stumped why I am getting this error.

Here is my list of packages and commands:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,referee]{svjour3} 

\smartqed 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage{subfigure}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{ntn}{Notations}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{as}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{ob}{Observation}[section]

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\def\div{\mathop{\rm div}}
\def\D{\mathop{\bf \rm D}}
\def\FP{\mathop{\rm p}}
\def\Span{\mathop{\rm Span}}
\def\boldalpha{\mbox{\boldmath $\alpha$}}
\def\boldpi{\mbox{\boldmath $\pi$}}
\def\boldzeta{\mbox{\boldmath $\zeta$}}
\def\boldtheta{\mbox{\boldmath $\theta$}}


\begin{document}

\section{Solution}\label{Solution}

\begin{lem}\label{conditions}
 Words for lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{mainthm}
 Words for theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{rem}\label{remone}
Words for remark
\end{rem}

\section{Analysis}\label{Analysis}

\begin{pro}\label{observation}
Words for proposition
\end{pro}

\begin{rem}\label{remtwo}
Words for remark
\end{rem}

\begin{thm}\label{secondthm}
Words for remark
\end{thm}

\begin{pro}\label{proposition}
Words for proposition
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This 'document' does not compile even after editing...

Comment: You should use `\spnewtheorem` and not `\newtheorem`.

Comment: Sorry, edited the document so that there is (hopefully) compilable code

Comment: Your code shows the use of `svjour3` and [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), and when I compile I receive an error (from `amsthm`) that the `proof` environment (or `\proof`, to be specific) is already defined. I would assume therefore that the class is not compatible with `amsthm` by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem-like environments should be defined, with the `svjour3` class, by using

```
\spnewtheorem
```

and not `\newtheorem`. Here's how you should do:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,referee,envcountsect]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\smartqed
\journalname{foo}

% Theorem-like environments are defined with \spnewtheorem
%
% Usage:
%
%     \spnewtheorem{env_nam}{caption}[within]{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem{env_nam}[numbered_like]{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem*{env_nam}{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}

\spnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{ntn}{Notations}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}% maybe \upshape?
\spnewtheorem{as}{Assumption}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{ob}{Observation}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} % \div is already defined
\DeclareMathOperator{\D}{\mathbf{D}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\FP}{p}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span}

\newcommand{\boldalpha}{\bm{\alpha}}
\newcommand{\boldpi}{\bm{\pi}}
\newcommand{\boldzeta}{\bm{\zeta}}
\newcommand\boldtheta{\bm{\theta}}


\begin{document}

\section{Solution}\label{Solution}

\begin{lem}\label{conditions}
 Words for lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{mainthm}
 Words for theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{rem}\label{remone}
Words for remark
\end{rem}

\section{Analysis}\label{Analysis}

\begin{pro}\label{observation}
Words for proposition
\end{pro}

\begin{rem}\label{remtwo}
Words for remark
\end{rem}

\begin{thm}\label{secondthm}
Words for remark
\end{thm}

\begin{pro}\label{proposition}
Words for proposition
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I left only the packages necessary for the example to run. Note also how I redefined your personal commands, in the correct way: in particular, ***don't*** redefine commands you don't know about (`\div`, in this case).

About the packages you load in the example:

- `amsfonts` is already loaded by `amssymb`
- `amsthm` is not compatible with `svjour3`
- `epsfig` must not be loaded in new document (it's just for back compatibility)
- `subfigure` has been obsolete for 10+ years, call

  ```
  \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
  ```

  instead; the `\subfigure` command becomes `\subfloat`.

About the theorem numbering: having separate counters for all kinds of statements is unnecessarily confusing for the reader, who will have hard times in finding the statements when referenced at: is lemma 1.1 before or after proposition 1.1?

Comment: Thank you, and everybody very much! The answers were all very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Actually I have tried the solution of `egreg`'s, and then find out that you don't need to create the command `\spnewtheorem{xx}{XX}[section]`

It is the option  `envcountsect` in the `svjour3` class that really helps.

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{svjour3}
```

If you look into the file `svjour.cls`, and seach `\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`, around line 888, you would find things like `@envcntsect` is prerequisite of the numbering by section.

And then, you just use

```
\begin{theorem}
    your theorem here.
\end{theorem}
```

to wrap your theorem. Proof, lemma, definition, case... are likewise.

Comment: I like to have all theorem-like macros numbered in one sequence (for example: Definition 1.1, Lemma 1.2, Theorem 1.3).  For that I added the `envcountsame` option: `\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsect,envcountsame]{svjour3}`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use  `\documentclass[natbib,smallextended, envcountsect]{svjour3}`