# Theorem Numbering in Springer Latex Class svjour3

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am using svjour3 class for writing a paper. I have set theorem counter subsection wise:

'''

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}     

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} 


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]


\begin{document}

\section{Section}   
\subsection{Subsection}  
\begin{thm}  
    Thorem Here.  
\end{thm}  

\end{document}
```

'''

This is giving the numbering as
**Section.Subsection theorem_number**. For example, the numbering is of the form **1.11** for the first theorem in **Section 1** and **Subsection 1.1**.

But I need the numbering to be **1.1.1** i.e. **Section.Subsection.theorem_number**.

Any help is deeply acknowledged.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237439/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you. It was helpful.